# How do I copy ADW launcher settings from the free to the paid app version?

Tags: adw.launcher, adw-launcher-ex

I want to upgrade from the free version of **ADW Launcher** to **ADW Launcher EX**.  How can I do this without having to re-create all of my app settings and widgets?

Answer (score 4):

Here is a partial solution (it doesn't copy widgets).

You must save the ADW settings as a backup in the free version, then restore them in the paid version.

1. Open ADW Launcher
2. Context menu > ADWSettings > System > Backup and Restore > Backup
3. Open ADW Launcher EX
4. Context menu > ADWSettings > System > Backup and Restore > Restore > (choose the backup time stamp you just created)
5. Context menu > ADWSettings > System > Restart ADW
6. Now you'll have to re-create your widgets.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your algorithm is right except one thing - you can't restore widgets if you are using Android ICS or older. This is limitation of OS. From [this post](http://adwthings.com/launcher/2012/10/adw-backuprestore/):

> NOTE 2: If you unfortunately have an Android device running anything
>   prior to Android 4.1, the widgets will not be restored.

And also from [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adw.launcher&hl=en):

> -AppWidget backup/restore (only for android 4.1 and newer)